# variable should visible to only present function in xtext

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, xtext

My output file:

```
reg1 {
field a field b
}

reg2 {
field c field d
}

FOREACH ( X IN reg1 ) {
X . a
}

FOREACH ( Y IN reg2 ) {
```

Now after this if I do ctrl+space I will expect only Y should pop-up. But X and Y both are getting pop-up.
How to restrict X to first FOREACH loop? out of first FOREACH loop X and its value should be erased. Please anyone suggest me how to implement this?

The related grammar rule is:

```
Model:
entities+=Entity+
uses+=Use+
;
Entity:
name=ID "{"
attributes+=Attr+
"}"
;
Attr:
"field" name=ID
;
Use:
"FOREACH" var=conds "{"
varref=[cond] "." attr=[Attr]
"}"
;
conds:
"(" cond1=cond ")"
| "," cond2=cond
;
cond:
name=ID "IN" entity=[Entity]
;
```

Scope provider :

```
public class MyDslScopeProvider extends AbstractDeclarativeScopeProvider {
IScope scope_Use_attr(Use ctx , EReference ref) {
return Scopes.scopeFor(ctx.getVarref().getEntity().getAttributes());
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you put a breakpoint into your scope implementation? You define a scope implementation for the `attr` but not for the `varref` of your grammar. Adding an implementation along these lines will do the trick.

```
IScope scope_Use_varref(Use ctx, EReference ref) {
  return Scopes.scopeFor(Collections.singleton(ctx.getVar().getCond1()));
}
```

Please note also that the parser rule `conds` seems to be bogus.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. Now it is working as I expected.